# asp.net user reset password control question/error!

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

Hi 
  I'm using the MS walk through to teach me how to build a simple ASP.Net web page
I followed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184050.aspx to create the site and login.

and then from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx i added the pw reset control.

the issue I have is that i create a test user i.e user name = test1 email=test@mydomain.com and pw=mytest

I can login ok, I can change passwords ok however when I use the Reset Password I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/Login' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.
```

Which is fine because the user name is not an Email address its test1!!! why is it looking for an email address?

If i enter the email address I get user not found which again is fine as there is no user test@mydomain.com because its Users test1's email...

What am I missing here?

A sneaky second question! Can I set the create user control to require me to approve the account?

Full Error:

### Server Error in '/Login' Application.

The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[FormatException: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.]
   System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ReadCfwsAndThrowIfIncomplete(String data, Int32 index) +1495521
   System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseDomain(String data, Int32& index) +118
   System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseAddress(String data, Boolean expectMultipleAddresses, Int32& index) +94
   System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseAddress(String data) +23
   System.Net.Mail.MailAddress..ctor(String address, String displayName, Encoding displayNameEncoding) +238
   System.Net.Mail.Message..ctor(String from, String to) +122
   System.Net.Mail.MailMessage..ctor(String from, String to) +114
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.MailDefinition.CreateMailMessage(String recipients, IDictionary replacements, String body, Control owner) +1396
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginUtil.CreateMailMessage(String email, String userName, String password, MailDefinition mailDefinition, String defaultBody, Control owner) +187
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginUtil.SendPasswordMail(String email, String userName, String password, MailDefinition mailDefinition, String defaultSubject, String defaultBody, OnSendingMailDelegate onSendingMailDelegate, OnSendMailErrorDelegate onSendMailErrorDelegate, Control owner) +371
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.PasswordRecovery.AttemptSendPasswordUserNameView() +566
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.PasswordRecovery.AttemptSendPassword() +62
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.PasswordRecovery.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +103
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +167
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Comment: It will need an email address to send the reset password to but you mention you set this to test@mydomain.com.  Can you post more info from the error - line numbers, call stack?

Comment: Have you created the password reset page? Could you check on the Reset Password button the event handler it is associated to?

Comment: @Paul, I have set the SMTP information up, however this seems to be failing on the form validation as if the user name has to be an eamil address, if so the user creation control doesn't enforce this hence how I have a user test1...

I just draged the the reset control on to a form setup the SMTP as per the steps in the second link above.

Comment: @HeloWorld (I like your user name!) yes I have created the page. I'm not sure how these hook up as it seems it does it for you! I assume there must be a validation property I have missed as its looking for an email not a user name but I don't know where or what it is. double clicking the button just takes you to an empty method...

Comment: Did you provide a `from` emailaddress?

Comment: I would go into the database and check that the test user's email looks correct, also double check your settings in the web.config.  Maybe even copy and paste these in to a telnet session to try and send email that way  http://www.wikihow.com/Send-Email-Using-Telnet

Comment: the problem I think is more basic then this. the Password Recovery control dragged and dropped from the toolbox login section it should take the user name but it validating it as if its expecting an email.

Comment: The error seems to relate to the email being sent.  What about putting an OnSendMailError event on the control and putting a breakpoint in to see what you have in the SendMailErrorEventArgs

Comment: Sorry all I feel silly it was as Caspar said simple I guess but I had missed it! Thank you all. @Caspar if you could put this as answer so I can mark it as such... thanks Caspar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a valid email `from` address in your MailSettings.

It is essential (but a common pitfall)